# Low-power water level alarm

Tags: sensor, low-power, 555, msp430, water

I'm trying to build a simple low-power water level alarm such that it could run continuously for at least 4 months on just 3x AA batteries. I've found this schematic which uses the 555 timer:

[image]

However, the 555 timer has a minimum power consumption of around 30mW, which would be too much. Would it be a good idea to modify the circuit such that the water's conduction supplies power to the 555 like so:

[image]

Is water conductive enough for this to operate?

Would it be a better idea to just use a low-power MCU like MSP430 and raise an interrupt when the probes short by water's conduction?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: In the above schematic, load current will flow through the water as well. IMO, you should drive a transistor via the conductance of the water.

Comment: Many embedded processors can go into deep sleep.  Some can drop down into the range of uA.  However, experience says, creating an over all design that doesn't leak current can also be a challenge.

Comment: the cmos version of the 555 has a power disapation of less than 1mW

Comment: @st2000 Could you elaborate on potential challenges?

Comment: I solved this problem by using a float switch.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Do you mean shorting a pin on the MCU with a float switch?

Comment: No, just a float switch and a MOSFET to switch a beeper. Being that sort of person, I did add a low power micro as a battery tester. It sleeps most of the time, wakes up and loads the battery/reads the voltage then goes back to sleep.

Comment: (@st2000 Could you elaborate on potential challenges) When you get into the uA range you have to think your design through.  Normally I wouldn't think twice about putting a 10K pull up on a N.C. switch to ground to pull the processor's pin up when the switch is activated.  But think about it, when that switch is closed it draws 500uA.  That washes away all the advantage of a, say, 10uA sleeping processor!  Welcome to the world of portable battery powered devices.

Comment: to add to @st2000's low power considerations: You wouldn't want to power up a bog-normal cortex-m0 without some 10nF–1µF capacitors to decouple the power supply. Now, sadly, leakage current in capacitors grows with capacity - and if your power-efficient MCU is on for only 0.001 of time, the leakage current in your caps will outgrow the actual power consumption of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

A few simple mods are all that is required. 
[image]

Add a p channel MOSFET to act as a ON/OFF switch for the 555. The circuit only draws current when the switch is activated.

The current through the MOSFET is small so anything that can carry 500 mA or more would be more than capable.

I've also simplified the oscillator to run from a single resistor (50% duty).

Answer (score 1):

However enticing such a cheap circuit may be, don't try it. Long-term reliability is very, very bad. The problem is that the presence of any moisture in your sense path will cause corrosion to form a crust on your probe due to galvanic action. This will take some time under normal conditions, but it will happen. At this point the circuit will stop responding to water when is does arrive.

Any such sensor must have an AC sensing voltage, with no trace of DC.

Comment: A very important point +1